# Cleanest way to access class member objects into an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, anonymous-function

I recently faced the classical problem of accessing class members into an anonymous function.

```
class A {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    printA() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }

    useAnonymousFunction() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.printA();
        })
    }
}

instance = new A(42);

instance.useAnonymousFunction();//TypeError: this.printA is not a function
```

The solution I found was to use the classical trick of storing "this" into an other variable.

```
useAnonymousFunction() {
    //that or self
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        that.printA();
    })
}
```

I used setTimeout in my example for readability but it could have been for setting an event or for an AJAX request.

This solution seems quite ugly. I tried to look for something more elegant but cannot find anything. There were some bind-based solutions but it seems like they don't work all the time (and they are even less elegant).

Is this solution really the norm even in EC6 ? Is using elements that use anonymous functions the real ugly part ?

Thank you in advance for your insight !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elegant solution you are looking for is using arrow function:

```
useAnonymousFunction() {
    setTimeout(() => this.printA())
}
```